# Insert Leads with active Assignment Rule through Dataloader

Tags: community, leads, lead-conversion

I want to insert 5000 leads using Data Loader, but I'm don't know how to active "Assign using active assignment rule" on insert. Is there a way to this on insert?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> Go to DataLoader Settings and follow the instructions in the
>   screenshot provided below:

[image: Assignment rule through Dataloader]

Please note, **the assignment rule overrides Owner values** in your CSV file and works for **Leads and Cases**.

Answer (score 0):

Within Data Loader Setting option there is an assignment rule ID.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the free Appexchange tool from WisdomEdge.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JLXVEA4

It exposes the assignment rules checkbox on Lead and Cases to be available through workflow rules. Just create a workflow rule to fire and check this box on create.